# Setting a field in model before saving the value Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have an object with date_posted field which is basically the day object was created using `auto_now_add = True`. In my form, I have a drop-down list with values. And I intend to add the value to an `expiry` field which is also aa DateTime object. Currently, in my view, I have:

```
 post = form.save(False)
 e = int(request.POST['expiry'])
 post.expiry = post.date_posted + datetime.timedelta(days=e)
 post.save()
```

however, I am getting this error:

```
post.expiry = post.date_posted + datetime.timedelta(days=e)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

I assume it's because my object hasn't been saved to the database yet. How can I add 'days' to the expiry field got from my form?

I have printed the e value and it is correctly received btw.

And I do not want to add date_posted now in save() method since it may cause issues with the automatic timezone set in Django

Comment: Why not save twice?

Comment: will that be optimal?

Comment: Probably not optimal, but definitely convenient. `date_posted` will be set by Django only after you call `save()`. So, first save to set `date_posted` and then save again to set `expiry`. A superior solution would be to save only once, but then it's only worth pursuing if performance demands it.

Comment: how can I manage to do that if I want to use it once?